# Merge two sorted arrays in runtime faster than O(N)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, linked-list, time-complexity

I think I have a solution but I am not completely sure.

My solution was to Convert Arrays to Linked Lists. Then Merge and sort the linked list recursively.

I've read that it will take O(1) space in memory. But I am not sure the runtime would be faster than linear time.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Without the code, there is no way to say.  The only way to reduce the time complexity is you have a large number of duplicates.

Comment: by merge do you mean that there shouldn't be duplicate?

Comment: How do you convert an array to a linked list in less than O(N)?

Comment: NO, it is NOT possible to merge 2 sorted arrays in less than O(n), n being the size of the biggest array

Comment: It's not possible to _read_ two sorted arrays faster than O(n), let alone do anything with them.  This is definitely 100% not possible.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is not possible in general. It depends on the use case. There are cases when you can say that statistically the merge will be faster than O(n).

Comment: "Not possible in general" means that in the general case it is not possible. There may be special cases where it is possible.

Comment: @DJClayworth if your comment is an answer to my comment, what I meant is more or less what you wrote, even though i wouldn't say that these are "special cases" if for special you mean also rare. They can be very common in some domains.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Perhaps [quantum bogosort](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuantumBogoSort)? O(1) ;-)

Comment: Are you looking for arrays only or any other data structure also.. as i think BST merging would be good and might do in <O(n)

Answer (score 2):

There is a special case where you can merge 2 arrays in constant time:

- The arrays are adjacent, that is they are slices of the same array and the last element of the first is just before the first element of the second.
- The last element of the first array is less or equal to the first element of the second array.

The case can be checked with a single test.

This may seem ludicrous, but it is a very common case for `mergesort` and testing for this special case first increases `mergesort` performance significantly for arrays that are already fully or partially sorted.  A similar test can be used to handle arrays that are sorted in reverse order, and carefully crafted code can achieve `O(N)` sorting times for both sorted and reverse sorted arrays while keeping the same number of element comparisons for the general case.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: it can also happen if the two lists are, for example, pixels of small segments : there could be a lot of pixels in each list, but you know that statistically there won't be overlap in most of the cases.

Comment: And even when there is an overlap, because they are sorted, you can use bisection to find the overlap and then check only the overlapped segment: operation that would take less than O(n)

Comment: LSNED about `mergesort()` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

> My solution was to Convert Arrays to Linked Lists.

That takes O(N) time and memory.

Comment: @DJClayworth am I misinterpreting the question? I thought this pretty directly answered whether the OP's algorithm is faster than O(N).